# How do I select offset documents in Kentico?

Tags: sql, where-clause, kentico

I'm trying to list several child pages based on most recent date, however for some sections I want the top 3 documents and some areas the rest of the articles from the same folder.

My current SQL statements is as follows:

```
DocumentId NOT IN ( IF EXISTS 
  ( SELECT DocumentId 
      FROM CMS_DocumentCategory 
      WHERE CategoryId 
      IN ({%CurrentDocument.Categories.IDs#%}) 
        and DocumentID <> {% CurrentDocument.DocumentId #%} ) 
BEGIN SELECT TOP 3 DocumentId
      FROM CMS_DocumentCategory 
      WHERE CategoryId 
      IN {%CurrentDocument.Categories.IDs#%} 
        and DocumentID <> {% CurrentDocument.DocumentId #%}
      ORDER BY Date DESC
END ELSE SELECT 0 AS [value] END )
```

However even after deleting the entire code block, the web part still shows just the top 4 or whatever choice that I have placed in the Top N Documents field.

I expect the output to be articles 4-6 for examples but I'm getting pages 1-3

Comment: it would be nice if you could provide more details. you've mentioned web part - is it a custom web part? how do you run the SQL query above? do you use custom query data source web part? how do you present data on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the logic correctly, but here is my 2 cents you can use sql TOP in 2 ways:

```
SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT  DocumentId  FROM CMS_DocumentCategory
```

or

```
SELECT  TOP 3  DocumentId  FROM CMS_DocumentCategory
```

So I would create a 2 properties for your page type:
First is **TopDocuments** which can be `TOP 100 PERCENT` or `TOP 3` and the other **DocumentsOrderBy** which can be empty  or  for example `ORDER BY DocumentCreatedWhen DESC` or whatever order

so your final query should be

```
DocumentId IN (  
SELECT  {%TopDocuments%}  DocumentId  FROM CMS_Document join CMS_DocumentCategory ON CMS_Document.DocumentID =  CMS_DocumentCategory.CategoryID
     WHERE CategoryId  IN {%CurrentDocument.Categories.IDs#%} and DocumentID <> {% CurrentDocument.DocumentId #%}
{%DocumentsOrderBy%}
)
```